# Loop through nested list and retrieve attribute (python)

Tags: python

I'm trying to loop through a json object to retrieve data in a list called `matched-bets` when I try this I get a `KeyError: 'matched-bets'`

How do I retrieve attribute from nested list?

```
data =[
  {
    'TIMESTAMP': '2019-01-20 04:56:54.609618',
    'id': 1019913470680020,
    'event-id': 1018510669860015,
    'event-name': 'Tomas Berdych vs Rafael Nadal',
    'market-id': 1018510670260016,
    'market-name': 'Moneyline',
    'market-type': 'money_line',
    'runner-id': 1018510670340016,
    'runner-name': 'Rafael Nadal',
    'sport-id': 9,
    'temp-id': '2.1547948212610',
    'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
    'side': 'back',
    'odds': 3.0,
    'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
    'decimal-odds': 3.0,
    'stake': 3,
    'remaining': 3,
    'potential-profit': 6.0,
    'remaining-potential-profit': 6.0,
    'commission-type': 'NET_WIN',
    'originator-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'acceptor-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'commission-reserve': 0,
    'currency': 'EUR',
    'created-at': '2019-01-20T01:36:58.498Z',
    'status': 'flushed',
    'in-play': False,
    'Latency': 0.074342
  },
  {
    'TIMESTAMP': '2019-01-20 04:56:54.609618',
    'id': 1019938516780022,
    'event-id': 1018426645920015,
    'event-name': 'Frances Tiafoe vs Grigor Dimitrov',
    'market-id': 1018426646320016,
    'market-name': 'Moneyline',
    'market-type': 'money_line',
    'runner-id': 1018426646390015,
    'runner-name': 'Frances Tiafoe',
    'sport-id': 9,
    'temp-id': '3.1547950690507',
    'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
    'side': 'back',
    'odds': 3.5,
    'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
    'decimal-odds': 3.5,
    'stake': 200,
    'remaining': 1e-05,
    'potential-profit': 500.0,
    'remaining-potential-profit': 3e-05,
    'commission-type': 'NET_WIN',
    'originator-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'acceptor-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'commission-reserve': 0,
    'currency': 'EUR',
    'created-at': '2019-01-20T02:18:43.108Z',
    'status': 'matched',
    'in-play': True,
    'matched-bets': [
      {
        'id': 1019941163310322,
        'offer-id': 1019938516780022,
        'odds': 3.5,
        'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
        'decimal-odds': 3.5,
        'stake': 102.84399,
        'potential-profit': 257.10998,
        'commission': 2.0568798,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'status': 'open',
        'created-at': '2019-01-20T02:23:07.761Z'
      },
      {
        'id': 1019941305850222,
        'offer-id': 1019938516780022,
        'odds': 3.5,
        'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
        'decimal-odds': 3.5,
        'stake': 97.156,
        'potential-profit': 242.89,
        'commission': 1.94312,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'status': 'open',
        'created-at': '2019-01-20T02:23:22.015Z'
      }
    ],
    'Latency': 0.080931
  },
  {
    'TIMESTAMP': '2019-01-20 04:56:54.609618',
    'id': 1020003691980022,
    'event-id': 1018426645920015,
    'event-name': 'Frances Tiafoe vs Grigor Dimitrov',
    'market-id': 1018426646320016,
    'market-name': 'Moneyline',
    'market-type': 'money_line',
    'runner-id': 1018426646390015,
    'runner-name': 'Frances Tiafoe',
    'sport-id': 9,
    'temp-id': '1.1547951656615',
    'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
    'side': 'lay',
    'odds': 1.25641,
    'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
    'decimal-odds': 1.25642,
    'stake': 200,
    'remaining': 0.0,
    'potential-liability': 51.28205,
    'remaining-potential-liability': 0.0,
    'commission-type': 'NET_WIN',
    'originator-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'acceptor-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'commission-reserve': 0,
    'currency': 'EUR',
    'created-at': '2019-01-20T04:07:20.628Z',
    'status': 'matched',
    'in-play': True,
    'matched-bets': [
      {
        'id': 1020008680510122,
        'offer-id': 1020003691980022,
        'odds': 1.25641,
        'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
        'decimal-odds': 1.25642,
        'stake': 200.0,
        'potential-liability': 51.28205,
        'commission': 1.025641,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'status': 'open',
        'created-at': '2019-01-20T04:15:39.481Z'
      }
    ],
    'Latency': 0.08113
  },
  {
    'TIMESTAMP': '2019-01-20 04:56:54.609618',
    'id': 1020020358220022,
    'event-id': 1018559986530015,
    'event-name': 'Danielle Rose Collins vs Angelique Kerber',
    'market-id': 1018559986940016,
    'market-name': 'Moneyline',
    'market-type': 'money_line',
    'runner-id': 1018559987020016,
    'runner-name': 'Angelique Kerber',
    'sport-id': 9,
    'temp-id': '5.1547958894686',
    'exchange-type': 'back-lay',
    'side': 'back',
    'odds': 2.36,
    'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
    'decimal-odds': 2.36,
    'stake': 200,
    'remaining': 1e-05,
    'potential-profit': 272.0,
    'remaining-potential-profit': 1e-05,
    'commission-type': 'NET_WIN',
    'originator-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'acceptor-commission-rate': 0.02,
    'commission-reserve': 0,
    'currency': 'EUR',
    'created-at': '2019-01-20T04:35:07.252Z',
    'status': 'matched',
    'in-play': True,
    'matched-bets': [
      {
        'id': 1020020481880222,
        'offer-id': 1020020358220022,
        'odds': 2.36,
        'odds-type': 'DECIMAL',
        'decimal-odds': 2.36,
        'stake': 199.99999,
        'potential-profit': 271.99999,
        'commission': 3.9999998,
        'currency': 'EUR',
        'status': 'open',
        'created-at': '2019-01-20T04:35:19.618Z'
      }
    ],
    'Latency': 0.08125
  }
]

for d in data:
   id = d['matched-bets'][0]['id']
   print(id)
```

Comment: There's most likely a discrepancy between what you have set in the `data` variable, and what you've pasted here. You seem to have copied json straight off (going by the `false` boolean), so confirm that the dictionary that's actually available in your code looks correct and has been read properly..

Comment: @WiggyA. I've just updated the question with the full json response. It does look correct to me too.

Answer (score 0):

`I tried your json object. I change "in-play": false,` to `"in-play": False,` and it's working fine.

Try to change `false` to `False`

**Update:**

```
import json

# its load your api data
json_data = json.loads(data)
# Convert to python object
python_object_data=json.dumps(json_data)

# 
for d in python_object_data:
   id = d['matched-bets'][0]['id']
   print(id)
```

If you use updated data format then use:

```
for d in data:
     print(d['id'])
```

Comment: The problem is I'm requesting this data from a third party api so If the data has a lower case bool does that mean the json is invalid? is there work around I can do to change false to False after response?

Comment: I've sent a new request and the new data has False instead of lower case. I've updated the question. I'm still receiving the key error

Comment: @Shaifkur Rahmanv I keep getting  a Type error with the updated answer

    id = d['matched-bets'][0]['id']
TypeError: string indices must be integers

Comment: What is your json format. You change json format in your question

Answer (score 0):

---

You can write like following,

```
for _d in data:
    if hasattr(_d, 'matched-bets'):
        print(_d['matched-bets']['id'])
```